# VS2010 IIS Express Security

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-7, ntfs, iis-express

I'm working on an MVC application where the end user has to upload a file, and the application needs to put the file on a local share (C:\Files).  The folder has wide open NTFS permissions (Everyone has full access), but when I try to upload the file, IIS Express barks at me, saying write access is denied.  Interestingly enough, if I blow away the directory, IIS Express has no problem recreating it, it just won't store anything in it.

It seems obvious this is a security setting with IIS Express.  Can someone tell me what setting it is, where it is, and what I need to change it to so that I can get this process to work?  I've seen a lot of similar questions, but they seem focused on NTFS permissions and the like, and I must assume that "Everyone" does in fact mean "Everyone".

**UPDATE** I added the Windows 7 tag as this may be related (64 bit)

Comment: Are having issues deploying your app or is your app having issues saving a file you upload?

Comment: I'm developing against my local machine using IIS Express.  Deploying is not the issue, just getting this one piece to work.

Comment: Can you please post the code that is doing the upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post your upload code? This one works fine for me:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads"), fileName);
file.SaveAs(path);
```

The above code works for both local IIS and a live site with MVC3 installed.

Comment: That almost identical to the code I have, except my path is "C:\files\" plus the `file.Filename`.

Comment: Are you using Windows 7? I had problems with file permissions when dropping and editing my SQL Server dbs. What I did was disable the UAT completely.

Comment: Ouch...  I really don't want to do that.

Comment: meh... I closed out of visual studio, went back in, and now it's working.  Riddle me that.